# App can not be installed via TestFlight: Registered maximum number of devices

Tags: ios, installation, testflight

Will appreciate any help with an error that is displayed when I try to install an app via TestFlight on an iOS device: " The app can't be installed because you've already registered the maximum number of devices".

Using the same user on another device works fine - app get installed.
Both devices are included in the provisioning profile UUIDs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Testflight Beta Testing?. Because Testflight is moved to Apple now

Comment: We are hitting the same issue. We are using Apple test flight.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

There is a maximum number of **10 devices** that can be registered to each user.

To remove a device from your user account:
1. Launch **TestFlight** on one of the devices you are signed in.
2. Tap on the "**Apple ID**" button at the bottom.
3. On the next screen click on the "**Edit**" button on the top right.
4. Select a device in the "**Other Devices**" section.
5. Click on the "**Remove(1)**" button on the top left.

**Note**:
You cannot remove more than 5 devices per week.

Comment: This is almost the correct answer, thanks a lot for this. I did have exactly 10 devices in the list, including the one where the installation has failed. What resolved the problem is removing it from the list of other devices and installing the app on it again, which went fine and was indeed successfully installed.

Comment: The answer is correct and worked for me.But I don't know how ten devices got added when I am using only four.I think apple is considering it as a new device when we reset a device to factory settings.

Comment: You can not remove more than 5 devices per week.
And yes, it seems that Apple is considering devices as new every time they are reset.

Comment: I still have this issue with a user who hasn't even installed the app on any devices yet.

Comment: Quick update: just removed 10 devices at once, so it seems the 5 devices per week limitation is not valid anymore.

Comment: According to the [TestFlight page](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/), the limit has been increased to 30 devices by member.

Comment: @Imran I think you're right about a factory reset counting as a new device.  One of my previous iPhones showed up as 3 separate devices, each one with a different major version of iOS.

Comment: Short update on this. Until now (2019) It is possible to add 30 devices to your TestFlight Account

Answer (score -9):

1) Testflight is moved to apple now. You have to use Beta Testing to test you application 
Follow this now -
https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

OR

2) If you still want to test using older way. Then there is alternative to testflight i.e
http://www.diawi.com/